# Formula for adjusting the length of an array / audio file in matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, math, octave

This is a followup question from:
[Time stretching signal / porting python code to matlab / octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362525/time-stretching-signal-porting-python-code-to-matlab-octave/27402713#27402713)

I'm trying to stretch a file a certain amount in seconds by changing the variable **dur**.

The length of the output file **(stretch.wav)** file should be the same as the **dur** variable
but it doesn't match up.  It varies depending on the sample size of the file.

I'm trying to figure out a way to calculate the correct number that the variable **stretch** should be by adjusting the formulas in the variable **dur** and the variable **stretch**.

*Note:  I'm trying not to alter the other code below those two variables (dur and stretch) due to the fact it would effect the way the signal is created.*

**The answers I get are below, as you can see they vary a lot when they are suppose to be close to 1800 seconds:**

```
inputfn = 1sec8000.wav
Original duration of file in seconds = 1.00 s
converted 1sec8000.wav =1.00(s) file to stretched.wav = 750.25(s)

inputfn = 1sec44100.wav
Original duration of file in seconds = 1.00 s
converted 1sec44100.wav =1.00(s) file to stretched.wav = 1378.25(s)

inputfn = 3sec8000.wav
Original duration of file in seconds = 3.00 s
converted 3sec8000.wav =3.00(s) file to stretched.wav = 1375.25(s)

inputfn = 3sec44100.wav
Original duration of file in seconds = 3.00 s
converted 3sec44100.wav =3.00(s) file to stretched.wav = 1684.47(s)
```

*PS:  I'm using octave 3.8.1 which works with matlab.*

See example working test code below:

```
urlwrite('http://www.onewithall.net/rttmpfiles/1sec8000.wav','1sec8000.wav'); %test files I used online
urlwrite('http://www.onewithall.net/rttmpfiles/1sec44100.wav','1sec44100.wav'); %test files I used online
urlwrite('http://www.onewithall.net/rttmpfiles/3sec8000.wav','3sec8000.wav'); %test files I used online
urlwrite('http://www.onewithall.net/rttmpfiles/3sec44100.wav','3sec44100.wav'); %test files I used online
inputfn='1sec8000.wav' %change this to test another file
[d, fs, bps]=wavread(inputfn);
inputlen=rows (d)/fs;

printf ("Original duration of file in seconds = %.2f s\n", rows (d)/fs);

dur=1800; %duration / length you want the file to be in seconds
stretch = dur/rows(d)*fs; %how much I need to stretch the file to get it to be the duration I want
windowsize = round (0.25 * fs);

step = round ((windowsize/2)/stretch);

## original window
fwin = @(x) (1-x.^2).^1.25;
win = fwin (linspace (-1, 1, windowsize));

#win = hanning (windowsize)';

## build index
ind = (bsxfun (@plus, 1:windowsize, (0:step:(rows(d)-windowsize))'))';
cols_ind = columns(ind);

## Only use left channel
left_seg = d(:,1)(ind);
clear d ind;

## Apply window
left_seg = bsxfun (@times, left_seg, win');

## FFT
fft_left_seg = fft (left_seg);
clear left_seg

#keyboard

## overwrite phases with random phases
fft_rand_phase_left = fft_left_seg.*exp(i*2*pi*rand(size(fft_left_seg)));
clear fft_left_seg;

ifft_left = ifft (fft_rand_phase_left);
clear fft_rand_phase_left;

## window again
ifft_left = bsxfun (@times, real(ifft_left), win');

## restore the windowed segments with half windowsize shift
restore_step = floor(windowsize/2);
ind2 = (bsxfun (@plus, 1:windowsize, (0:restore_step:(restore_step*(cols_ind-1)))'))';
left_stretched = sparse (ind2(:), repmat(1:columns (ind2), rows(ind2), 1)(:), real(ifft_left(:)), ind2(end, end), cols_ind);
clear ind2 ifft_left win;

left_stretched = full (sum (left_stretched, 2));

## normalize
left_stretched = 0.8 * left_stretched./max(left_stretched);
printf ("converted %s =%.2f(s) file to stretched.wav = %.2f(s)\n", inputfn, inputlen, rows (left_stretched)/fs);
wavwrite (left_stretched, fs, bps, "streched.wav");
%system("aplay streched.wav")
```

Comment: For followup questions it would be nice of you to indicate where you got the code from (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27402713/ )

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
windowsize = round (0.25 * fs);
```

Means the windowsize for your FFT chunks is 0.25 seconds long. If your inputfile is only 1s longs, this means the rounding error for

```
step = round ((windowsize/2)/stretch);
```

gets really big because my code uses full windows for reconstruction. If you want an exact length I suggest adding an additional reconstruction window and the crop the output to you desired length.

Btw, your 1s input files contains only one sinus period. This can't be stretched by this code because of aliasing effects.

Comment: what do you mean by adding another "reconstruction window"?